# How to access realm model/realmObject from react native in android studio

Tags: android-studio, react-native, realm-mobile-platform

Reffer to [the tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/integrating-realm-database-in-an-android-application/) there's a code to creating **`realm model`** in android using `extends realmObject`

in my case, **`realm model`** already declared in path :

> myReactNative->App->Data

which 2 file inside `Data` folder is :

`DB->db.js`

```
import Attachment from '../Models/Attachment';
modelSchema = [
    Attachment
];
export default new Realm({ schemaVersion:1, schema: modelSchema});
```

and `Models->Attachment.js`

```
import Realm from 'realm';
export default class Attachment extends Realm.Object {}
Attachment.schema = {
    name: "Attachment",
    primaryKey: "attachmentID",
    properties:{
        attachmentID: "int",
        auditFindingListID: "int",
        url: "string",
        extension: "string",
        type: "string",
        createdBy: "string",
        createdDate: "date",
    },
};
```

the issue is my android project path is :

> myReactNative->android(importing to android studio)

so I can't access the **`realm model`** in android studio,

There's any way to make it works?

Comment: why do you want to?

Comment: @IshitaSinha because i've using android studio for development, so i need to connect those RN project into android file, and now the problem is about connecting realm into android

Comment: The tutorial you mentioned in your question is for Java, not for React Native. I don't quite understand why you're using AS if you're developing only in RN and not in Java? All the files inside `android` are android specific.

Comment: @IshitaSinha basiclly im an android studio dev, and i've reffered [native modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html), because i dont know how to do in RN, i want to create a native module from android studio to brige it into RN, FYI: RN project is about team dev,

Comment: then you should refer to [this](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/?_ga=2.44355684.1954534509.1510819701-1630970655.1510819701) instead of trying to do it in such a complicated way.